# Zend_Http_Client failes to decode reply?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to use Zend_Http_Client to fetch a specific page (www . nu . nl)
I am using this code

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url,
    array(
        'maxredirects' => 5, 
        'timeout' => 30,
        'useragent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:0.9.3) Gecko/20010801 '
    )
);
$code = $client->request("GET");
$pageBody = $code->getBody();
```

For this specific site, `$pagebody` is empty (0). Using xdebug, it seems that it fetches the encoded response but fails on the decoding. Also, and this is wierd to me, sometimes it works with no problem!

I would appreciate any thoughts on how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be a bug - if so it's worth checking for an existing bug at http://framework.zend.com/issues/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa and posting reproducible steps to get it fixed if there isn't already an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I am not able to reproduce your problem.

```
$url = 'http://www.nu.nl';
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url, array(
    'maxredirects' => 5,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'useragent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:0.9.3) Gecko/20010801 '
));

$response = $client->request("GET");
$pageBody = $response->getBody();
var_dump(strlen($pageBody));
```

Output: int(36902)

Comment: Yes, I can't reproduce it at this time as well. I notice they use " 
Juniper Networks NitroCache/v1.0" so it is possible that there was a glitch on the server side and not on the framework. I will be monitoring it for the next days. Stupidly enough, I did not record the unencoded data on the first day I noticed the problems.

Comment: I actually reproduced it after all and submited it as a possible bug:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10179?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel